# Can I show different results from an API using Postman

Tags: api, postman, postman-testcase

I have an dummy API which throws a response of 0 and 1, how can I get different responses with it using Postman. ie When I Hit the API if it throws a response of 0 it should show a different message and same goes with 1

I didn't know the approach

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a feature in the Postman application to change the response value based on the response received through an API call.
But there is a feature to [Mock Responses in Postman](https://blog.postman.com/mock-responses-in-postman-by-using-examples/#:%7E:text=Edit%20the%20request%20part%20of,builder%20to%20save%20your%20example.)